# Looking up global variables instead of constructing them inside a c++ function

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern

### Question:

I have some functions that are being called a **lot**. Inside each function, local variables are constructed. These variables are usually `Eigen::MatrixXd`s that are sort of small (usually under 10 x 10). Every call constructs the same variable, over and over again, then discards it.

I started thinking it would be faster to define these variables outside of the function, and then look them up.

1. Why is the "looking up" of some global variable likely to be faster than re-constructing it over and over again?
2. Should I put the global constants in a namespace? What could go wrong with this approach?

### First Code:

I started off with these three files.

First: `functions.h`

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <Eigen/Dense>

Eigen::MatrixXd getMatrix();

#endif //FUNCTIONS_H
```

second: `functions.cpp`

```
#include "functions.h"

Eigen::MatrixXd getMatrix()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd myMatrix(4,4);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        myMatrix(i,i) = 3.0;
    }
    return myMatrix;
}
```

Third, `main.cpp`

```
#include "functions.h"

int main()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
        getMatrix();

    return 0;
}
```

### Second Code:

First, `functions2.h`:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS2_H
#define FUNCTIONS2_H

#include <Eigen/Dense>

extern const Eigen::MatrixXd myMatrix;

Eigen::MatrixXd getMatrix2();

#endif //FUNCTIONS2_H
```

then `functions2.cpp`

```
#include "functions2.h"

const Eigen::MatrixXd myMatrix = Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(2,2);

Eigen::MatrixXd getMatrix2()
{
    return myMatrix;
}
```

then a different `main.cpp`

```
#include "functions2.h"

int main()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
        getMatrix2();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not ask for a reference to a matrix built in main() and fill that reference? Did you really measure the performance here or you are assuming that doing that will improve your application?

Comment: Is your code slow? Does it need to perform better? If not, then don't do anything. Else you measure and profile to find the bottlenecks and concentrate on fixing *those* instead of blindly fixing what you *think* might be slow. Always code for simplicity, readability and maintainability first and foremost. Then if the performance is not up to requirements you find the bottlenecks and optimize them, one by one, until the performance is okay.

Comment: @Ceros and @Someprogrammerdude I did with gprof. The biggest bottlenecks are all a bunch of calls of really long-named functions inside `Eigen.` All I'm doing is sampling and inverting a bunch of these matrices. And yes, it needs to be faster.

Comment: I am no familiar with Eigen but I believe that you would get a copy-elision in your case http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision "When that local object is constructed, it is constructed directly in the storage where the function's return value would otherwise be moved or copied to."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `get` functions will always be returning the same matrix, you can generate it once the first time it is needed, without using a global variable, by using a static local one.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd getMatrix()
{
   static Eigen::MatrixXd myMatrix{[](){
        Eigen::MatrixXd m(4,4);
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            m(i,i) = 3.0;
        }
        return m;
    }};
    return myMatrix;
}
```

This uses a lambda function to initialize the matrix, rather than another function.  It will also create a *copy* of the matrix every time, but the original matrix is hidden from all users and cannot be changed.  Copy elision cannot happen here, since the source is not a non-static local variable.  RVO  can still be done.

Another option here is to return a reference to the matrix, by changing the function to

```
const &Eigen::MatrixXd getMatrix()
```

This will avoid the copy and still hides the original matrix from changes unless the caller applies a `const_cast` to the returned value.

For `getMatrix2`, you can just move the global variable you have into `getMatrix2` as a static.

Answer (score 1):

In general

1. Say it takes 1 second to write the matrix into memory and one second to read it. If you write it once, using a global variable  or a variable in main, and you read it N times, this takes 1 + N*1 seconds. If you recreate the object every time you want to use it, this takes 2*N seconds.
2. It might be a good design decision to put constants in a namespace that makes sense for them. Maybe you would put "pi" in your math namespace, for example. [Where should you put global constants in a C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387083/where-should-you-put-global-constants-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 1):

Globals are quite possibly slower.

That might be a bit of a surprise but often starting with a clean sheet is cheap. Globals have the downside that all code could change them, which can hamper optimization.